# Frame transfer rate problem in python socket programming

Tags: python, sockets

I use the TCP protocol, but the higher the video quality, the lower the transfer speed.
How can I find a solution? Is replacing video codecs a solution? (internet speed maximum 72mb / s)

Comment: You could compress the data before sending it.

Comment: Please show a *"Minimal Complete Verifiable Example"* of your code and details of your video frame size, type and codec along with what you have measured so far. Also details of your operating system and network infrastructure. Else we are guessing. Thank you.

Comment: Nothing clear in the question !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to enhance transmission speed you should:

- increase the buffer size on the receiving side (because otherwise, your server has to send more packets == more overhead and dead time)
- Compress the data using a common compression like the Python-standard [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) if it's rather text-based or use another video codec (As mentioned in the comments)
- Ensure that your data can be read fast enough before sending
- Ensure that your data can be written fast enough after receiving

*If you need more details, leave a comment*